# Is there an API to fetch collection-level NFT stats from 0x orders like floor price, total volume, etc?

Tags: nft, 0x

Opensea and Looksrare offer collection-level NFT stats API endpoints (i.e. https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-collection-stats and https://looksrare.github.io/api-docs/#/Collections/CollectionController.getCollectionStats).  These include floor price and historical volume data.

I'm just wondering if the same sort of data exists somewhere for 0x NFT stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment we don't offer this; however, some recommended tools/thoughts from our Trader.xyz team:

(top pick) https://module.readme.io/reference/retrieve-collection-floor

and

https://api.reservoir.tools/#/2.%20Aggregator/getEventsCollectionsFlooraskV1

While these tools aren't 0x specific, floor prices are somewhat universal, so these tools should do the trick.